# If i change the duplicated array element value, main array element also changed, why?

Tags: ruby

**Code**

```
max = 99
nums = max.to_s.split('')
(0..nums.length - 1).each do |i|
    dup = nums
    p 'dup', dup
    p 'nums', nums
    dup[i] = '6'
end
p 'result', nums
```

**Output**

```
"dup"
["9", "9"]
"nums"
["9", "9"]
"dup"
["6", "9"]
"nums"
["6", "9"]
"result"
["6", "6"]
```

in 1st iteration `dup = nums` will work, while 2nd time iteration `dup = nums` will not set the nums values, **Why?**

Why nums array value will change if I set the dup value(`dup[i] = '6'`)

Comment: Because `dup = nums` means `dup` and `nums` are the same object. You could change this to `dup = nums.dup`

Comment: You should also do the `dup` operation outside the loop.